# How to assign pgtype.UUIDArray to []uuid.UUID?

Tags: postgresql, go, struct, uuid, pgx

I use Go + Postgres. To work with Postgres I use [pgx](https://github.com/JackC/pgx).
I have an array of UUID in my Postgres table and a Struct with []*uuid.UUID (from [github.com/gofrs/uuid](https://github.com/gofrs/uuid)) in Go (see code below).

The problem is that I always get error when I try to use AssignTo function

> cannot: decode &pgtype.UUIDArray{Elements:[]pgtype.UUID(nil),
>   Dimensions:[]pgtype.ArrayDimension(nil), Status:0x2} into *[]*uuid.UUID

(I have tried to use all combinations with pointers and it doesn't work)

My struct (for API):

```
type Book struct {
    AuthorIds []*uuid.UUID `json:"author_ids"`
}
```

My struct (for working with Postgres):

```
type PgBook struct {
    AuthorIds pgtype.UUIDArray `db:"author_ids"`
}
```

And I use `AssignTo` function from `pgx`

```
err := pgBook.AuthorIds.AssignTo(&book.AuthorIds)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: And `uuid.UUID` is from ... ?

Comment: From gofrs package https://github.com/gofrs/uuid (i wrote it in the title)

Comment: You might be able to do it by changing the `Book`'s field to `AuthorIds []uuid.UUID` (i.e. slice of non-pointers). If not you'll have to first assign to something that pgx understands and then manually set the `Book`'s field.

Comment: ... i.e. declare a variable of type `[][16]byte`, pass a pointer to it to `AssignTo`, after that returns loop over that variable and convert each element into a `uuid.UUID` and append that to the destination slice.

Comment: I have tried []uuid.UUID bit it does not work too. But the strange part is that AssignTo works well with pgtype.UUID (p.s. I have uuid field in db), but not pgtype.UUIDArray

Comment: I have thought that I did mistake. If not (it is pgx error) I will do it manually